# EC2 instance reach ability check fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance on aws, when I tried to start that instance it gives me error EC2 instance reachability check fail  on "Instance Status Checks" I tried to troubleshoot with creating a new instance with same market place and in the same region and attached the volume but I am getting the same error on new instance after attaching the volume.

I have few backups on S3 is there any way to restore backups from S3 to ec2 instance.

and system logs showing following 
 2.594228] List of all partitions:
[    2.599278] No filesystem could mount root, tried: 
[    2.606695] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    2.607685] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 ve: 0 Not tainted 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.el7.x86_64 #1 29.2
[    2.607685] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 08/24/2006

please suggest !!
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you checked the attached Security Group? Can you attach a screenshot of its contents?

Comment: Yes I attached security group and all traffic allowed to outbound 0.0.0.0/0 and inbound I have configuration of different port but all traffic again allowed on port 80

Comment: We need a bit more info. Are you running this instance in a default vpc, or a vpc which you have made?

Comment: I updated the question with some log, does it will help you to figure out

Answer (score -3):

That is no serious matter actually. Just hit "Stop" wait until it stops completely and then hit "Start" again then wait to complete its initialization.

It will not be going to show that error again.

Comment: That mostly happens to micro instances so it is because of the high number of traffic